# Is there any way to remove blank lines inside blocks and comments in PhpStorm in CSS files?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

In PhpStorm (and I suppose IntelliJ), there are quite a few options for removing blank lines in various code languages.

For CSS, there is not even a tab, just an option to set "Blank lines *between* blocks".

**Is there any way to tell PhpStorm to remove blank lines *inside* blocks (and possibly comments) when clicking "Reformat code"?**

**Update:** Here's my settings tab:
[image: Settings]

[image: Useless empty lines]

Comment: **For code blocks** -- yes -- it should remove such blank lines automatically -- does for me (Show your settings if it does not). **For comments** -- no. **In any case:** You may install and use **String Manipulation** plugin that has separate action to remove empty lines in selected text.

Comment: Thanks - no, it doesn't. I am referring to CSS - it works in php and other languages. Thanks also for the plugin hint - I'll try that.

Comment: These are mine -- working great for me: http://postimg.org/image/5f7likewj/ . See if it will make any difference on your end. If it does not: please share your whole Code Style (`File | Export Settings`) as well some sample .css file (so that we both check the same code).

Comment: @LazyOne - wow, that did it for me! I believe it is the setting "Blank lines between blocks" = 0 that made the difference. Still, I believe that this functionality could be improved in PhpStorm so that blank lines between blocks can be kept while blank lines inside of blocks are removed. Feel free to add this as a regular answer.

Comment: BTW, exporting setting returns a jar file (which I'd have to decompile, I guess, to get text, but I have no Java environment here).

Comment: JAR file is just a regular ZIP archive -- there is nothing to decompile.

Comment: If it only works with `0` as a value ... then I may suggest to submit a ticket to their Issue Tracker at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI -- possibly it's a bug (unless we both misunderstood what that option does).

Comment: Should have known about JAR format. Anyway, we don't need it anymore. Seems to be a bug indeed, or a very strange misunderstanding. Thanks a bunch for your help. I'll submit a ticket.